# Is it possible to read a mac installation file on ubuntu

Tags: package-management, wine, packaging, macosx

I want to use a piece of [Windows] software that runs using Wine on a Mac but only comes shipped as a Mac package (or a Windows download). Is it possible to load that into Wine on Ubuntu?

The issue I have is that there is some executable that gets installed for this software (and possibly some auxiliary files), but I don't know what they are.  You don't download them directly.  You download a package (setup.exe or mac.dmg) that installs them.  So, I don't know what to install on my Linux system.  It's all behind the curtain "magic".

Comment: No, Wine is for Windows software.

Comment: The problem is the underlying software *is* Windows software, but they offer a mac package for it, that runs it with wine.  I want to use that package on Linux, but I don't know how to "extract" the relevant file and compose the appopriate wine command.

Comment: Why not use the Windows download directly with wine?

Comment: If I knew how, what options or whatever the mac package used to run it, I would.  Which is why I am wondering if there is a way to decode what the mac package is doing.  The Windows version comes as a setup.exe which I figure I have even less chance of deciphering.

Comment: "What the mac package is doing" No. Proprietary software is proprietary. And this, to me, is too vague; there is no 1 fits for all method when it comes to wine.